# Getting multiple properties associated with click events

Tags: javascript

I'm rank new to javascript thus the question.

I'm using data-id to pass an idea associated with a click event.

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} data-id={image.id}>
```

This is my handle click method,

```
handleClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let mediaId = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-id'].value;
    this.props.handleClick(mediaId);
  }
```

Now I want to capture one more attribute, which is the image.src Where do I place that data and how do I get the data in my click event handler.

Comment: have you tried `event.currentTarget.attributes['src']` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have both attributes as `data` attributes if you want:

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} data-id={image.id} data-src={image.src}>
```

And then access them as different attributes

handleClick(event){

```
    event.preventDefault();
    let mediaId = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
    let src = $(event.currentTarget).data('src');
    this.props.handleClick(mediaId);
  }
```

Hope this could help.